# How to check missing values in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table that is filled with data every 15 minutes. I need to check that there is data for all days of the entire period. there is a time column in which the data is in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

i've found the start date and the last date with

I found out that you can generate an array of dates from this interval (start and end dates) with which each line will be compared, and if there is no match, here it is the missing date.

i've tried this:

```
WITH dates_range AS (SELECT toDate(min(time)) AS start_date,
                            toDate(max(time)) AS end_date
                     FROM table)
SELECT dates
FROM (
         SELECT arrayFlatten(arrayMap(x -> start_date + x, range(0, toUInt64(end_date - start_date)))) AS dates
         FROM dates_range
         )
         LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT toDate(time) AS date
    FROM table
    GROUP BY toDate(time)
    ) USING date
WHERE date IS NULL;
```

but it returns with Code: 10. DB::Exception: Not found column date in block. There are only columns: dates. (NOT_FOUND_COLUMN_IN_BLOCK) and I can't

Comment: It depends, why do you need it?

Comment: join wont work in case of BIG data.

Comment: you can generate all required dates and using `union all` find where there are occurrences in generated data and holes in the source data (I would use it).

Comment: I need to create an alert that informs me if there are missing data by dayю I need to check the table so that the data is for all days and there are no gaps. for example, I have data for 2023-01-01, 2023-01-03, 2023-01-04 and so on. 2023-01-02 is missing

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `WITH FILL` modifier https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/order-by/#order-by-expr-with-fill-modifier

```sql
create table T ( time DateTime) engine=Memory
as SELECT toDateTime('2020-01-01') + (((number * 60) * 24) * if((number % 33) = 0, 3, 1))
FROM numbers(550); 

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toDate(time) AS t,
        count() AS c
    FROM T
    GROUP BY t
    ORDER BY t ASC WITH FILL
)
WHERE c = 0
┌──────────t─┬─c─┐
│ 2020-01-11 │ 0 │
│ 2020-01-13 │ 0 │
│ 2020-01-16 │ 0 │
│ 2020-01-18 │ 0 │
│ 2020-01-21 │ 0 │
│ 2020-01-23 │ 0 │
│ 2020-01-26 │ 0 │
└────────────┴───┘
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table T ( time DateTime) engine=Memory
as SELECT toDateTime('2020-01-01') + (((number * 60) * 24) * if((number % 33) = 0, 3, 1))
FROM numbers(550); 


select b from (
SELECT
    b,
    ((b - any(b) OVER (ORDER BY b ASC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING))) AS lag
FROM
(
    SELECT toDate(time) AS b
    FROM T
    GROUP BY b
    ORDER BY b ASC
)) where lag > 1 and lag < 10000
┌──────────b─┐
│ 2020-01-12 │
│ 2020-01-14 │
│ 2020-01-17 │
│ 2020-01-19 │
│ 2020-01-22 │
│ 2020-01-24 │
│ 2020-01-27 │
└────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table T ( time DateTime) engine=Memory
as SELECT toDateTime('2020-01-01') + (((number * 60) * 24) * if((number % 33) = 0, 3, 1))
FROM numbers(550); 

WITH (SELECT (toDate(min(time)), toDate(max(time))) FROM T) as x
SELECT l.*, r.*
FROM ( SELECT arrayJoin(arrayFlatten(arrayMap(x -> x.1 + x, range(0, toUInt64(x.2 - x.1+1))))) AS date) l
         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT toDate(time) AS date FROM T GROUP BY toDate(time) 
    ) r USING date
WHERE r.date IS NULL settings join_use_nulls = 1;

┌───────date─┬─r.date─┐
│ 2020-01-11 │   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 2020-01-13 │   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 2020-01-16 │   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 2020-01-18 │   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 2020-01-21 │   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 2020-01-23 │   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 2020-01-26 │   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└────────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Thx, this one is convenient resulution!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table T ( time DateTime) engine=Memory
as SELECT toDateTime('2020-01-01') + (((number * 60) * 24) * if((number % 33) = 0, 3, 1))
FROM numbers(550); 


WITH (SELECT (toDate(min(time)), toDate(max(time))) FROM T) as x
select date, sumIf(cnt, type=1) c1, sumIf(cnt, type=2) c2 from
(  SELECT arrayJoin(arrayFlatten(arrayMap(x -> x.1 + x, range(0, toUInt64(x.2 - x.1+1))))) AS date, 2 type, 1 cnt
      union all SELECT toDate(time) AS date, 1 type, count() cnt FROM T GROUP BY toDate(time) )
group by date
having c1 = 0 or c2 = 0;
┌───────date─┬─c1─┬─c2─┐
│ 2020-01-11 │  0 │  1 │
│ 2020-01-13 │  0 │  1 │
│ 2020-01-16 │  0 │  1 │
│ 2020-01-18 │  0 │  1 │
│ 2020-01-21 │  0 │  1 │
│ 2020-01-23 │  0 │  1 │
│ 2020-01-26 │  0 │  1 │
└────────────┴────┴────┘
```